# On button-click download file from server

Tags: python, http, unix, confluence

I have python script that generates excel file, is it posible to add a link or macro or something that could trigger a button click in confluence page and downloads a file from a server. I have never done this with confluence.

Or from python side - to generate a link via the file could be triggered and downloaded on button click. Or there could be python libs..

Help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. I read how to achieve it via curl, but it's more from server side, but I'm looking to achieve this from confluence page itself. So that doesn't suit me. I saw there is `confluence-rest-library` and `atlassian-python-api` libs that I'm reading atm.